# Keras save_weights h5 file appears empty

Tags: keras, serialization, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to save/load weights from a custom keras model but the resulting file appears empty, and the weights aren't restored.

What am I missing?

```py
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import h5py


class M(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.w = self.add_weight(name='w', shape=())

    def call(self, x, *arg):
        return self.w.numpy()

m = M()

with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w') as f:
    m.save_weights(f.name, save_format='h5')
    print(m(1), m.get_weights())
    # 0.14819694 [0.14819694]

    m.set_weights(np.array([43]))
    print(m(1), m.get_weights())
    # 43.0 [43.0]

    m.load_weights(f.name)
    print(m(1), m.get_weights())
    # 43.0 [43.0]

    with h5py.File(f.name, mode='r') as h5:
        assert 0 == len(list(h5))
```

Comment: What do you mean "appears empty"? What is the evidence of that?

Comment: Added evidence. But that's kinda not the point. Is something wrong with the save-load workflow? It doesn't matter if I use a temp file or just a file.

Answer (score 0):

The weights aren't saved because of [this line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/8a96b50/keras/engine/training.py#L2195):

```
hdf5_format.save_weights_to_hdf5_group(f, self.layers)
```

that is responsible for the h5 format. In the model, there are no layers. It does work with the `tf` format though.